# Error running Sonar SSLR Toolkit

Tags: python, sonarqube, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to add a new rule for my Python project, so according to this source ([Adding Coding Rules using XPath](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules+using+XPath#AddingCodingRulesusingXPath-WritinganXPathRuleusingSSLRToolkit)), I was trying to run sslr-python-toolkit-1.9.1.2080.jar from command line to view AST of a given piece of code but it exited with the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/sslr/toolkit/ConfigurationModel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.sslr.toolkit.ConfigurationModel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Am I missing something? How could I make it work? I'm quite new in SonarQube arena, so please excuse my naivety and help me to solve the issue. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a serious bug indeed. I just logged an [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-283) so that it get fixed in the next version. Thanks for reporting it!

As a workaround, you may use an [older version of the SSLR Toolkit](http://downloads.sonarsource.com/plugins/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/python/sslr-python-toolkit/1.5/sslr-python-toolkit-1.5.jar) which seems to work. It's based on an older version of the parser, so it could give different results in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-Yves for showing the workaround, it's working for me (at least the parsing part seems to be working). Hope the bug will get fixed in later version.